# How to get ID from table only if it contains multiple values needed, from different rows

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a `channel_members` table containing `channel_id, user_id`. I need to get the `channel_id` if there are multiple rows using that same `channel_id` which contains multiple `user_id` that I will provide.

Example: 
If there are 5 rows in the table

```
CHANNEL_ID | USER_ID   
2          | 2   
2          | 3   
2          | 4   
3          | 2   
3          | 4
```

I need to get the `channel_id` which are being used by `user_id` 2, 3, and 4. So based in the table above that I provided. I should get `channel_id` 2.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I changed my question as I what I actually need is the channel_id. I need to get the channel_id if the user_ids that I have are using that channel, otherwise if at least one of the user_Id is not using that channel_id, returning nothing is okay.

Comment: Try this: `SELECT channel_id FROM channel_members 
GROUP BY channel_id
HAVING COUNT(channel_id) > 0`

Comment: But that does not check whether user 2, 3, and 4 are using the same channel

Comment: `SELECT channel_id FROM channel_members WHERE user_id IN (2,3,4) GROUP BY channel_id HAVING COUNT(channel_id) > 0`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have already defined your relations uisng models, As per your provided description, channel has many to many relation with user

```
class Channel extends Model
{
    public function members()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'channel_members', 'channel_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Using eloquent realtions you can check existance of related models as

```
$channels = App\Channel::whereHas('members', function ($query) {
                        $query->where('id', '=', 2);
                    })->whereHas('members', function ($query) {
                        $query->where('id', '=', 3);
                    })->whereHas('members', function ($query) {
                        $query->where('id', '=', 4);
                    })->get();
```

Above will return you only channels who have associations with all 3 users based on supplied id

[Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CHANNEL_ID 
FROM channel_members 
WHERE USER_ID in (2,3,4)
GROUP BY CHANNEL_ID 
HAVING COUNT(CHANNEL_ID) > 0
```